# Rails 3, how add a associated record after creating a primary record (Books, Auto Add BookCharacter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails newbie... trying to understand the right way to do things...

In my app users can create a Book ( I have that working)

What I want to happen is when a user creates a book, a record is added to the BookCharacters Table, something like (id, book.id, user.id, characterdescription.string.)

When the book is created, the user who created it should automatically be added as the first BookCharacter. After than the user can then manually add/edit as many BookCharacters as they want. But initially I want them added automatically by default.

So in my Book controller I have:

```
def create
 @book = Book.new(params[:book])
 respond_to do |format|
  if @book.save
....
```

With Rails, is it the practice to add that kind of logic after the book is saved? Something like

```
Book.create( :creator => current_user.id)
```

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The important thing to understand is the convention by which Rails implements relationships using ActiveRecord. A book has many characters, and each character belongs to a book, so:

```
class Book < ActiveRecordBase
  has_many :characters
end

class Character < ActiveRecordBase
  belongs_to :book
end
```

Rails now assumes that the `characters` table will have a foreign key called `book_id`, which relates to the `books` table. To create a character belonging to a book:

```
@book = Book.new(:name=>"Book name")
@character = @book.characters.build(:name=>"Character name")
```

Now when `@book` is saved (assuming both `@book` and `@character` are valid), a row will be created in both the `books` and the `characters` tables, with the character row linked through `book_id`.

To show that a character also belongs to a user, you could add that relationship to the Character model:

```
class Character < ActiveRecordBase
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Thus Rails now expects `characters` to also have foreign key called `user_id`, which points to a `users` table (which also needs a `User` model). To specify the user when creating the character:

```
@book = Book.new(:name=>"Book name")
@character = @book.characters.build(:name=>"Character name",:user=>current_user)
```

You can also assign the foreign key by calling the corresponding method on the object:

```
@character.user = current_user
```

This all works because it follows the Rails conventions for naming models and tables. You can depart from these conventions, but you'll have a harder time learning Rails if you do.

Comment: That's the best answer I've ever seen. Thanks for helping me understand the right way to use Rails

Comment: hi thank you @zetetic - if i have two models that are related to each other, then when I create an instance of the first, i have to manually create an instance of the second and join them together in the controller, rather than have rails automatically create the second record upon the creation of the first --> is that the rails convention? chrs

Answer (score 0):

I prefer something like (if User has_many Book):

```
def create
 @book = current_user.books.new(params[:book])
 respond_to do |format|
  if @book.save
  …
```

Comment: Thanks but My question was about creating BookCharacters... Maybe I can edit to clear that up better?