# Rails 4 Create Associated Object on Save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, after-save

How can I create multiple associated objects automatically just after I save a new primary object?

**For example**

In Rails 4, I have three objects: **Businesses**, **Budgets**, and **Categories**.

```
#app/models/business.rb
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
   #attrs id, name
   has_many :budgets
end

#app/models/budget.rb
class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base
   #attrs id, business_id, department_id, value
   belongs_to :business 
   belongs_to :category
end

#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   #attrs id, name
   has_many :budgets
end
```

When I create a new Business, after saving the new Business, I would like to atomically create a Budget for each Category and give it value of $0. This way, when I go to show or edit a new Business, it will already have the associated Categories and Budgets, which can then be edited. Thus, upon creating a new Business, multiple new Budgets will be created, one for each Category, each with the value of 0.

I read this article: [Rails 3, how add a associated record after creating a primary record (Books, Auto Add BookCharacter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739158/rails-3-how-add-a-associated-record-after-creating-a-primary-record-books-aut)

And I am wondering if I should use the after_create callback in the Business model and have the logic then exist in the Budgets controller (not exactly sure how to do this) or if I should add logic to the businesses_controller.rb in the 'new' call with something similar to:

```
@business = Business.new
@categories = Category.all
@categories.each do |category|
      category.budget.build(:value => "0", :business_id => @business.id)
end
```

Comment: It looks like there is extraneous information here that makes this question difficult to answer. Does a business really have a budget in addition to department budgets? Also for a department to have many businesses and vice versa, there needs to be a join table that appears to be missing.

Comment: Thanks. A Business has_many budgets. Departments are more like categories of budgets, so I suppose they don't need an association to a Business. Thus, Budget is the join table. I have updated the question. If you have a better suggestion for entity names, please suggest them.

Comment: I updated the question to remove the association between Departments and Businesses and renamed Departments to be Categories. Hopefully this will make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the logic to the create method in the Business controller to loop through all Categories and create a budget just after save. Note that I was lazy and didn't put in any error handling. :

```
  def create
    @business = Business.new(params[:business])

    @results = @business.save

    @categories = Categories.all

    @categories.each do |category|
      category.budgets.create(:amount => "0", :business_id => @business.id)
    end


    respond_to do |format|
      ...
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, it's best to avoid using callbacks unless it relates to a given model's persistence. In this case, letting a budget set it's own default value when one isn't supplied is good use of a callback. That also removes some complexity from your logic.

```
class Budget
  before_validate :set_value
  ...
  private

  def set_value
    self.value ||= 0
  end 
end
```

For the rest, I would create custom classes, each with a single responsibility, to systematically generate a new business. Here's an example. Keep in mind that this is not meant to be copy and pasted, it's just to illustrate a concept:

```
class BusinessGenerator < Struct.new(:business_params)

  attr_reader :business

  def generate
    create_business
    create_budgets
  end

  private

  def create_business
    @business = Business.create!(business_params)
  end

  def create_budgets
    BudgetGenerator.new(@business).create
  end
end

class BudgetGenerator < Struct.new(:business)

  def generate
    categories.each do |c|
      business.budgets.create!(category: c)
    end
  end

  private

  def categories
    Category.all
  end
end
```

This is nice because it separates concerns and is easily extensible, testable and doesn't use Rails magic like accepts_nested_attributes_for. For example, if in the future you decide that not all businesses need a budget in every category, you can easily pass the ones you want as an argument to BudgetGenerator.

You'll instantiate the BusinessGenerator class in the controller:

```
class BusinessController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def create
    generator = BusinessGenerator.new(business_params)
    if generator.generate
      flash[:success] = "Yay"
      redirect_to generator.business
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
  ...      
end
```

Some sticking points you might have with this approach include:

- Returning validation errors to your business form
- If the creation of a budget fails, you're stuck with a budget-less business. You can't wait to save business until after the budgets are created because there is no id to associate. Perhaps consider putting a transaction inside of the generator method.

Comment: This would be a great example of extracting a service pattern. (See [#2 here](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/))

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of `Brent Eicher`'s great advice, I've never experienced anything bad from using callbacks. If you don't mind using them, you could do the following (*if* you're setting the budget at `0` each time):

```
#app/models/business.rb
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :build_budgets

   private

   def build_budgets
      Category.all.each do |category|
         self.budgets.build(category: category, value: "0")
      end
   end
end
```

--

Also, you need to make sure your `budget` foreign keys are correct.

I see you have `department_id` when `Budget belongs_to Category`. You should make this `category_id` *or* define the foreign_key:

```
#app/models/budget.rb
class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category, foreign_key: "department_id"
end
```